# Gradle play plugin property testClassesDirs missing in gradle 3.1

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I want to use `Gradle 3.1` and Gradle `play plugin`. I have to add a task.

Can you help me to parse below snippet from version `4.0` to `3.1`?
I can't find the analogous property `testClassesDirs` in Gradle 3.1

```
task doesNotWorkIn3_1(type: Test) {

    dependsOn { tasks.compilePlayBinaryTests }
    testClassesDirs = project.files { [tasks.compilePlayBinaryTests.destinationDir] }
    classpath = project.files { testPlayBinary.classpath }
    include '**/SwaggerControllerJsonTest.class'
    outputs.upToDateWhen { false }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
task genSwaggerJson(type: Test) {
    dependsOn { tasks.compilePlayBinaryTests }
    testClassesDir = file("$buildDir/genSwaggerJson_testClasses")
    classpath = files({ tasks.testPlayBinary.classpath })
    outputs.upToDateWhen { false }
    include '**/MySingleTest.class'
}
```

This one works fine for 3.1

Answer (score 0):

Like you said, the problem is with `testClassesDirs`, it exists in Gradle 4.x but not in Gradle 3.1.

So please update

> testClassesDirs = project.files { [tasks.compilePlayBinaryTests.destinationDir] }

to

```
testClassesDir = tasks.compilePlayBinaryTests.destinationDir
```

Let me know if this works.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but it didn't help. I've provided answer on my own

Comment: @Sergey I did not see the difference between your answer and mine, what is the error?

Comment: Also, I think somehow your own answer is different from your original question (from file folder perspective).